# Get the row number of filtered data only

Tags: excel

I have a list with 300.000 data points filtered to a list with 2000 data points+.
And I want to create a list with the row numbers of only the visible data (filtered data).

Example:
Unfiltered List:

| Date | Data |
| --- | --- |
| First | data1 |
| Second | data2 |
| Third | data3 |
| Fourth | data4 |

Filtered list:

| Date | Data |
| --- | --- |
| First | data1 |
| Fourth | data4 |

excel *ROW*-function:

| Row Number |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 4 |

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Do you mean, if only two rows are visible, that they should be numbered 1 & 2?

Comment: Add a column with `=ROW()-1` and include that in the range to filter?

Comment: i´m filtering: contains and need the new table with the row numbers in a new sheet.

Comment: Are you filtering by formula? `= FILTER(...)` - Where do you get the filter criteria from?

Comment: im filtering a colum with a keyword (if the keyword is contained it is filtered) and now i need the row numbers of the filtered data to compare it.

Comment: But how - are you doing this manually via the filter-option or via VBA or via a formula (using e.g. `FILTER`)??

Answer (score 0):

There are two tasks here related, but they are not the same. Filtering the data, can be achieved as follow in cell `F2`:

```
FILTER(A2:B5, ISNUMBER(XMATCH(A2:A5,D2:D3)))
```

and here is the output:

[image: sample excel file]

We use `FILTER(array, include)`, where `include` input argument needs to satisfy the following requirements: *A Boolean array whose height or width is the same as the array*.

The way to build such array is via `XMATCH(lookup_value, lookup_array)` function. It returns an array of the same size as `lookup_value`, with the index position of `look_array` where a match was found, otherwise returns on a given position `#N/A`. Adding the logical function `ISNUMBER` we ensure it returns an array with `TRUE/FALSE` values. Doing this way we are able to satisfy `FILTER` input argument requirements.

For the second part of the question, we can use a similar idea, modifying the `FILTER` `array` input argument as follow in `H2`:

```
=FILTER(ROW(A2:A5), ISNUMBER(XMATCH(A2:A5,D2:D3)))
```

Another alternative (that was not mentioned in the comments) is via `XLOOKUP`:

```
=XLOOKUP(D2:D3,A2:A5,ROW(A2:A5))
```

The new `XLOOKUP(lookup_value, lookup_array, return_array)`. It allows us to specify the returning array (the old version `VLOOKUP` doesn't), so now we can refer to the absolute row position of `A2:A5` via `ROW` function.

So it will return the following array with the row positions:

```
2 -> row of First
5 -> row of Fourth
```

If you want to filter the data not using a `FILTER` function, but using Excel UI (User Interface), it is easier, you just need to apply `ROW` function to the filtered data. The original rows of the data before filtering remains the same.

[image: Filter data using Excel UI]

Comment: but its not working for me, following problems:
-row() not working! always puts out 1 if i define the array
-xlookup would be nice but doesnt work because its not a perfect match! i need a contains search because the colum im searching in is a huge string (numbers and chars).

Comment: @Max you can try `XLOOKUP` with input argument `match_mode` for approximate search. You didn't state in your question no exact match. I would suggest to create another question that represents better your specific situation. I was trying to respond to your requirements. About `ROW`I am not sure what you are doing, I reproduced your problem and it worked for me. Share the link of your file, so I can have a better idea.